# Java example to convert FlashAir decimal 16-bit integer to date/time format?

Tags: java, flashair

In retrieving the file list from FlashAir 2nd gen using their command cgi as explained here: [FlashAir Get List CGI Command](https://flashair-developers.com/en/documents/api/commandcgi/#100) I get decimal 16-bit integers to represent the date and time of the file.

The specification (in the link posted) explains how to understand the retrieved values, but it lacks a Java example. I tried downloading and inspecting Android sample code posted in the FlashAir Developer's Website [FlashAir Tutorial for Android - Downloading Content](https://flashair-developers.com/en/documents/tutorials/android/3/), but they just use the file names, so they do not perform any conversions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just extract the bits as specified.

Assuming you have a `short time` and `short date`:

```
int seconds = (time & 31) * 2;
int minutes = (time >> 5) & 63;
int hours   = (time >> 11) & 31;
int day   = date & 31;
int month = (date >> 5) & 15;
int year  = ((data >> 9) & 127) + 1980;
```

Then just make a datetime out of that.

It's not clear whether the raw years can be negative. I wrote it such that they can't be, if they're supposed to be able to be negative (to represent dates before 1980) just remove the `& 127`.